# Calculating the time to perform work on rolling shutters

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, power

I have rolling shutters, e.g.:

[image]

I am trying to determine how much **time** it takes to raise/lower the shutters a specific amount. (Because of the physics involved, the time is non-linear relative to the amount of shutter movement.)

This is very similar in concept to a winch raising/lowering a weight.

I found an excellent tutorial of (what I believe to be) a related example, pulling a heavy rope + weight up the side of a building: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJF_34TSAwQ

So, using this formula, I can calculate the total work in raising the blinds a specific amount:

$$W = \frac{r *(h1^2 - h0^2)}{2} + (h1 - h0) * w$$

where:

- W = work
- r = lb/ft of shutters material (e.g., cloth)
- h1, h0 = ending and starting heights
- w = mass of dowel/rod on bottom of shutters

If it takes 10 seconds to move from the bottom to the top, then I calculate motor power as:

$$P = \frac{W}{t} = \frac{W}{10}$$
where:

- W = work
- P = Power
- t = time

Presuming I'm doing this correctly so far, I can determine the amount of seconds (t) it will take to move from any position to another by just considering the work it would take to move from position 1 to position 2 and the power of the motor. I'm also assuming the motor has a fixed power, which I think should be a reasonable assumption.

(I'm neglecting any acceleration time for when the motor powers on for now, but if this is easy to add, would love to add that too).

The part that has me confused is that empirically I know that the time to lower the shutter is less than the time to raise it, because of gravity.

The tubular motor still controls the descent, but is there some way to account for gravity in these calculations?

Comment: There is a wonderful basic guide to using MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This will make it easier for us to read your question.

Comment: You can calculate work done easily by taking the difference between initial and final potential energy of the shutter.

Comment: @Sam thanks for the input. I revised the formulas. I can calculate the work as I described, but I'm trying to solve for TIME. Roll up time != roll down time.

Comment: The answer is likely more closely related to the mechanics of the door raising/lowering system than it is to the work done. Almost certainly, the motor will have a speed governor  of some sort to stop the door rocketing up and/or down, so the opening /closing time may be more influenced by that than by the work being done. The door opening/closing mechanism also quite likely uses something like a worm-gear so the door will stop at any position if the motor is turned off. If that is the case, then gravity is of almost no assistance in closing the door.